# Meaning of “the picture outraged polite society”

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

What does mean this sentence? Does it mean:

The picture is outraged by polite society.

or Polite society is outraged by the picture.

> the picture outraged polite society

Comment: "Pictures" are inanimate objects that can't (even "figuratively") experience the emotion of ***outrage***. On the other hand, "polite society" (along with "Disgusted, of Tonbridge Wells" in the UK) is stereotypically outraged at a great many things..

Comment: @FumbleFingers T**u**nbridge Wells?

Comment: [Disgusted, of Tunbridge Wells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disgusted_of_Tunbridge_Wells)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second one is the right one: "*Polite society is outraged by the picture*".

Semantically, it is impossible for an image to be outraged so your first option wouldn't work, but it's also an incorrect interpretation, syntactically.

Comment: What are you meaning by syntactically? and how will it be correct?

Comment: By syntactically I mean that it's a problem of syntax, not just meaning, so even if the noun was something else it couldn't mean your first option. "*The [A] [verb] [B]*" doesn't mean "*The [A] is [verb] by [B]*".

Comment: @Boyep The first sentence is not incorrect (not grammatically at least), but it doesn't have the same meaning as the sentence in the title.